# Is there a way to access previously discovered Wi-Fi access points?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, discovery

In Android, I am using `wifi.startScan();` to manually start a Wi-Fi scan every X seconds and then storing all found entries into a List of ScanResult in a BroadcastReceiver. This methodology is energy consuming.

It is my understanding that Android will scan for Wi-Fi discovery anyway. Is there a way for me to access the nearby access points that Android captures anyway?

Answer (score -1):

You can use (e.g. in `onCreate()` of you activity)

```
MyReceiver receiverWifi = new MyReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    // You can get the results here of the built in android wifi scan
    wifiManager.getScanResults();
}
```

keep in mind that you need these permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: What about getting the scan results without calling getScanResults()? Is there a way to register a receiver which would get triggered when the latest access point scan results are updated?

Comment: I am sorry I mixed something up. I've edited my answer so it should be more clear. Just register a reciever on the 'android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS' and get the ScanResults() in the receiver